# Push new values to the top without removing the existing in array in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, export-to-csv

I am facing issue with pushing new values into an array. I am getting the values in response which I am writing to excel in header row. I have some static fields which I want to push to the same response and push everything to csv to write all the values into header row rather than new lines. But, whatever the values I am adding explicitly to the response, I want those to be displayed in the starting columns of the csv. But those were being displayed in the last. Can someone help me with this? I want the explicitly added values to be displayed in the starting of csv file.

Here is my code:

```
csvDownload() {
    let fields = [];
    this.service.attrValues()
      .subscribe((response) => {
        response.push(
          { 'field': 'Test1'},
          { 'field': 'Test2'}
        );
        fields.push(response.map(x => x.field));        
      },
      (err) => {
        this.display.Error(err);
      }, () => {
        this.downloadFileToCsv(fields);
      }
      );
  }

  downloadFileToCsv(fields) {
    var options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: true,
      useBom: true
    };
    new Angular2Csv(fields, 'test', options);
  }
```

Comment: Can you use `unshift()`? [doc link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

Comment: I tried adding 'fields.unshift('Test1'); after 'fields.push(....)'. Still no luck. It is adding this value in the top. But all the remaining data is being written in next line. But only this one in the 1st row. That too all the words were written in different column i.e, T , e, s, t, 1

Comment: it worked. I replaced 'response.push' with response.unshift' and fields.push with fields.unshift. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can learn more from here : [javascript array methods](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm)